# Installing Silverlight OOB with Safari 6.1

Tags: macos, silverlight, safari, silverlight-oob, out-of-browser

it seems that Safari 6.1 on Mac (recently updated) does not allow a user to install a silverlight OOB application from a website. Is there any work around/fix for this?

With older versions of Safari or other browsers, it is simple to just right click the silverlight app and hit 'Install', but with Safari 6.1, nothing happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to go to Safari --> Preferences... --> Security --> Manage Website Settings... and search for Silverlight on the list. You'll need to select the "Run in Unsafe Mode" either for just your site or all sites.

Seems like the sandbox restrictions are tighter by default now.